# Fill in a Text Box on a Website with Ruby

Tags: ruby, text, web-scraping

I was wondering if there was a way or a library that could fill in a text box on a website that Ruby connects to. I am working on a web-scraping application that pulls a table from a website... Here is the text box I am referring to:

[image: The text box]

Is there an easy way to do this or a library I could use?

(All the different pages of data are in one url so I can't use a different url to do this).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question  is asking for us to recommend solutions, which is off-topic. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably try [mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) gem which allows you to do this:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page  = agent.get('http://google.com/')

form = page.forms.first
form['field_name_1'] = input1
form['field_name_2'] = input2

page = agent.submit(form, form.buttons.first)
puts page
```

It's quite easy to use and very intuitive. Here is the [documentation](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/) with [more](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html) [examples](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html).

Or you can use Developer tools of your choice in your favorite browser to record and inspect the HTTP request after that form submission and then use standard [HTTP Client](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) to send a direct request to the site (form action) with all the POST request data prepared (instead of feeling a form).

If you are going to scrap a lot of data I would suggest using something like [em-http-request](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request) to do it asynchronously.

Answer (score -1):

You 'll have to use a test gem , some to fill form inputs .
Like ["capybara"](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)

The documentation is a bit exhaustive , but it's a powerfull tool